# What is Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "invalid opcode: CHAINID" }

Tags: go-ethereum, evm, governance

I have deployed a new EVM based blockchain using geth, and deployed an ERC20 token on it successfully but when I tried to deploy an ERC20 token for voting purposes on governance contract I faced with the error and also getting same error with governance contract.

```
creation of MyToken errored: Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
  "code": -32000,
  "message": "invalid opcode: CHAINID"
}
```

code of erc20 vote token:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/draft-ERC20Permit.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Votes.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, ERC20Permit, ERC20Votes {
    constructor() ERC20("TestT", "TES") ERC20Permit("TestT") {  
        _mint(msg.sender, 100000000000000000000000);
      }

    // The functions below are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _afterTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount)
        internal
        override(ERC20, ERC20Votes)
    {
        super._afterTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    }

    function _mint(address to, uint256 amount)
        internal
        override(ERC20, ERC20Votes)
    {
        super._mint(to, amount);
    }

    function _burn(address account, uint256 amount)
        internal
        override(ERC20, ERC20Votes)
    {
        super._burn(account, amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: we need more code and details

Comment: @MajdTL code is same as in openzeppelin documentation `https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/governance`, as I told above it deploying fine on rinkeby testnet but not on my custom chain.

Comment: So we have to specify something in config file to deploy governance contract?

Comment: @MajdTL i have added the code in question.

Comment: @MajdTL I was deploying directly through metamask